# NHibernate using QueryOver with WHERE IN

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover, where-in

I would create a QueryOver like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Field IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I've tried with `Contains` method but I've encountered the Exception

> "System.Exception: Unrecognised method call: System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)"

Here my code

```
var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<MyModel>(() => baseModel)                                                                
  .JoinAlias(() => baseModel.Submodels, () => subModels)
  .Where(() => subModels.ID.Contains(IDsSubModels))
  .List<MyModel>();
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of `IDsSubModels`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I've found the solution!! :-)

```
var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<MyModel>(() => baseModel)
    .JoinAlias(() => baseModel.Submodels, () => subModels)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => subModels.ID).IsIn(IDsSubModels)
    .List<MyModel>();
```

Comment: better in this way .WhereRestrictionOn(() => subModels.ID).IsIn(IDsSubModels)

Comment: Faber, your comment should be placed in your answer since .Where(Restrictions.In(subModels.ID,IDsSubModels)) won't work if i try it. your comment does work.

Comment: what if the the "list" from the "IN" query is a list of objects?

Comment: Use IsIn for a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 52):

You can try something like this:

```
// if IDsSubModels - array of IDs
var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<MyModel>() 
                       .Where(x => x.ID.IsIn(IDsSubModels))
```

You don't need a join in this situation

Comment: This would filter by MyModel.ID, not by MyModel.Submodels.ID as @Faber wanted, right?

Comment: x here is the instance of MyModel class, same as instance\record of Table in your SQL request.

    SELECT *     FROM Table     WHERE Field IN (1,2,3,4,5)

And x.ID in (1,2,3) is same as Table.Field in (1,2,3). 1,2,3 is IDsSubModels

Answer (score 13):

This works and is more elegant

```
var Strings = new List<string> { "string1", "string2" };

var value = _currentSession
.QueryOver<T>()
.Where(x => x.TProperty == value)
.And(Restrictions.On<T>(y=>y.TProperty).IsIn(Strings))
.OrderBy(x => x.TProperty).Desc.SingleOrDefault();

where T is a Class and TProperty is a property of T
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've used your syntax, but I forgot to publish here ;)