# QueryOver IN Clause?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I want to simulate this query:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

How can I do this in FNH?

```
var ids = new List<int>{1,2,3};
var results = session.QueryOver<Foo>().Where( x=> ids.Contains(x.id) );
```

But that does not work, just gives me an "unrecognized method call" exception.

Any ideas?  This must be a common request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate using QueryOver with WHERE IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408781/nhibernate-using-queryover-with-where-in)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Aha- got it!  The AddRestrictions has an IsIn method:

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Foo>().AndRestrictionOn(x=>x.id).IsIn(ids)
```

With this last piece we might be ready to ditch our years-old hand-rolled ORM!

Comment: [Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/kenny-evitt/9121755) with an example of the SQL generated by this.

Comment: You can also use WhereRestrictionOn instead of AndRestrictionOn

Comment: what is the definition of the "ids" ?